# Scanner for missing translation keys in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am wondering if there are any tools available to scan for missing translation keys in a Rails application. eg if I have in my code <%= t :Submit %> but my English translation file does not contain submit: submit, I would like to be able to run a tool that tells me which keys are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) does exactly this:

[image: i18n missing translations]

It scans calls such as `I18n.t('some.key')` and provides reports on key usage, missing, and unused keys. It can also can pre-fill missing keys, including from Google Translate, and it can remove unused keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be exactly what you're looking for: http://mentalized.net/journal/2009/08/10/find_missing_translations_in_your_rails_application/

It looks like it's on Github, too: http://github.com/koppen/i18n_missing_keys

EDIT: I answered the wrong question. New answer:

If you have enough integration tests, I think, in theory, all the missing keys should fire their `I18n::MissingTranslationData` exceptions. This might be helpful in making that process easier: http://dev.innovationfactory.nl/2009/05/04/rails-i18n-caveats-and-tips/#translations

Sorry that I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Yeah, that’s not what I’m looking for – as far as I can tell it just compares translation files and finds keys that are in one but not another. I already have a script to accomplish that. What I need is something that will scan the application itself and find references to keys that do not exist in any translation file.